# Two derived classes returning each other's type in method

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

I've got a situation similar to this:

B.hpp

```
class B {...};
```

D1.hpp

```
class D1 : B {
    D2 conversion_method(){ D2 d2(); ... return d2; };
}
```

D2.hpp

```
class D2 : B {
    D1 conversion_method(){ D1 d1(); ... return d1; };
}
```

So those classes need to know each other's definition to return proper types, how would I go about this type of problem? I need those methods to return types (not pointers) because that is the interface requirement.

Comment: Use a forward declaration and pointers or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done, but not with inline function declarations.

Both classes need to forward-declare each other, in their header files, i.e.:

```
class D2;

class D1 : B {
    D2 conversion_method();
}
```

and

```
class D1;

class D2 : B {
    D1 conversion_method();
}
```

Then, somewhere, in some third header file or some `.cpp` file, which must include both header files, you can define both `conversion_method`()s, since both classes' definitions are now available.

With some crafty use of additional `#include`s, and preprocessor macro handling, it would be possible to arrange things so that once both header files get `#include`d, that results in both implementations of `conversion_method`()s getting defined automatically. This is done by having each header file `#define` something, and `#include` a third header file afterwards. The third header file checks if both `#define`s exist, and proceeds and defines both `conversion_method`()s. This effectively accomplishes the same thing as your original intention was.

Comment: Separate .cpp file for defining methods seems to be working like a charm :) Thanks!